# Turn by turn feature on iOS6

Tags: ios, mapkit

Hi I am trying to get the route between 2 points using Mapkit on iOS6. Idea is to get the route and overlay on the map. But the only way to get Turn by tun is using the map application or launching the map application with URL.

Can be get the Turn by turn feature without closing the app on iOS6?

Answer (score 0):

You can use web view for this and open safari in UIWebView only and now you can navigate to your app by just adding a navigation bar for it.

Use below code for it:

```
    MKCoordinateRegion region = { {0.0, 0.0 }, { 0.0, 0.0 } };
    region.center.latitude = getLatitude;
    region.center.longitude = getLongitude;

    MKCoordinateRegion currentRegion = { {0.0, 0.0 }, { 0.0, 0.0 } };
    currentRegion.center.latitude = currentLatitude;
    currentRegion.center.longitude = currentLongitude;
    region.span.longitudeDelta = 4.0f;
    region.span.latitudeDelta = 4.0f;
    currentRegion.span.longitudeDelta = 4.0f;
    currentRegion.span.latitudeDelta = 4.0f;

    CLLocationCoordinate2D start = { currentRegion.center.latitude, currentRegion.center.longitude };
    CLLocationCoordinate2D destination = { region.center.latitude, region.center.longitude };


    NSString *googleMapsURLString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://maps.google.com/?saddr=%1.6f,%1.6f&daddr=%1.6f,%1.6f",start.latitude, start.longitude, destination.latitude, destination.longitude];

    NSURL *url=[NSURL URLWithString:googleMapsURLString];
    NSURLRequest *requestObj=[NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
    [webView loadRequest:requestObj];
```